What do I do with a question that got solved in the comments?
The question How can I fix the Alduin’s Bane quest bug where the dragon doesn’t show up at the Time-Wound on Switch? is a "how to fix this bug" question that the OP (say they) solved in comments.
Do I close it? If so, what close reason do I use? Or do I flag it with another reason? Or do I do something else?

I would say to leave the question untouched, then post the comment where OP said what they did that fixed it in an answer, giving attribution to the OP.
Alternatively, if OP is still active, you can ask them to do it and accept their answer when they’re finished.

Daemons's answer is sufficient.  I think what most people try first is to get the OP of the comment to write an answer of it, that way they can get credited with some reputation from an accept vote/upvotes.  But if the user is no longer active or otherwise never posts their answer, I think what most people do is take the comment and self-answer as a community wiki and give credit to the OP.
You won't gain any reputation from a wiki answer however.  I'm not opposed to you posting it as a non-wiki answer either if you gave the OP a chance first.

Yeah this is what I do. I'm also not opposed to simply posting them as a non-CW answer and crediting the OP (if the OP hasn't responded in a few days and/or hasn't been on site in months)
